# ERROR 2003 (HY000) cant connect to mysql server on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I installed Lamp and started all services. I run following code with shell (cmder):

```
$ mysql
```

I got this error

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000) cant connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10061 'Unknown error')
```

I have already installed wamp and this code work correctly in mysql console.

Can any one explain this error?

Comment: restart your windows

Comment: I restarted once. but its not work.

Comment: Use WAMP's interface to stop/start services

Comment: you haven't told mysql what user to use for logging in , u must specify the user with -u option and then tell it to log in as "root"

Comment: so what is the command?

Comment: @PKa have updated my answer check it

Answer (score 1):

You may have to go to your /bin folder and from there run

```
mysqld
```

[check this out](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-start-command-line.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysq15.5.24\bin>mysql

ERROR 2003 (HY000) cant connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10061 'Unknown error')
```

the error message is because you haven't told mysql what user to use for logging in. You
must specify the user with the `-u` option and then tell it to log in as `"root"`. Here's how it looks:

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5\bin>mysql -u root
Welcome to the MYSQL  monitor. Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MYSQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.5.24-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
mysql>
```

Comment: Can you explain by Lamp?

Answer (score 0):

I am running mysql on windows 8 and fixed this error by going into 
c:\mysql\bin and right clicking the "mysqld" file and choosing run as. 
Choose the first option (current user etc..) and hit ok.